# How to resolve jquery conflict with another library

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/TitilliumText.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/shortcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/custom.js"></script>

</head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
</body>
```

Bear with me as I am pretty new to web development and just got thrown into this project.

I'm implementing fancybox which requires jQuery to be loaded. However, there appears to be some type of conflict with `scripts.js` and `custom.js` as when I include them fancybox doesn't work. Unfortunately, I need to include both of those scripts.

I have tried using `jQuery.noConflict();` in multiple places to no avail. I'm not sure where to go from here

Here are the two problem .js files (if relevant).

custom.js:

http://pastebin.com/SBqGXAqR

scripts.js:

http://pastebin.com/fz1GhaSH

Comment: What errors do you get in you javascript console? **(F12)**

Comment: *"Doesn't work"* is not a useful problem description.

Comment: Console shows no errors.

Comment: Doesn't work as in the expected behavior of opening the photo in a "lightbox" doesn't occur. it just opens the photo as an external link. it does nothing

Answer (score 2):

check it

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

and take care, with other libraries who use holders like jquery's "$"

if you implement the noConflict you have to call jquery functions like this

```
jQuery(document).example();
```

Answer (score 2):

Call jQuery.noConflict() prior to loading custom.js or add it to the beginning of the file, then modify each

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

Inside those functions you can use the $ as you normally would

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox is a jQuery plugin, documented to work with the `$` selector. You should remove any `jQuery.noConflict()` calls, since they will require changing every use of `$` in all of your scripts.

Have you checked the javascript console for errors?

If there is no information in the console, then it will be much easier to identify the problem if you first narrow down the amount of code that could be responsible. Verify that Fancybox works when you remove both `scripts.js` and `custom.js`, then check if it works with only `custom.js` removed. Once you identify the file responsible, comment out the bottom half of the modules in the file responsible and check again. Keep adding half of the modules back in and rechecking until you find the module that causes the problem.